# Devise Token Auth / Angular2-Token, update password, Completed 401 Unauthorized

Tags: authentication, angular, rails-api, devise-recoverable

I'm having troubles restoring password with devise_token_auth. and Angular2-Token. I'm successfully receiving the email with the link to update my password. But I'm getting an 401 Unauthorized response when submiting the new password.

Front end. I'm getting the token from the URL with `urlParams.get('token')`

```
  onPasswordUpdate() { 
    let token = this.urlParams.get('token');
    var obj = Object.assign(this._updatePasswordData, { reset_password_token: token })
    this._tokenService.patch('auth/password/', obj ).subscribe(
      res =>    res,
      error =>  error
    );
  }
```

Back end response.

```
Started PATCH "/api/auth/password/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-01 21:17:48 +0100
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::PasswordsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

In the link of the email I get the following token :  `reset_password_token=HneZDoKTMCLF3_SLfnxy`
When I visit the link, the user record gets updated with the following attributes :

```
reset_password_token: "aa3cba76c7b1d8f78cde6856f43e1cce57f5fc8e5301842733de677eff909bc1"
tokens: {}
```

Then in the browser URL I get the following `token=agejaip2SqOp9nvwE1GAHQ&uid`
And then the user record get updated with the following attribues :

```
...
reset_password_token: "HneZDoKTMCLF3_SLfnxy",
tokens: {"pv9i1BDTM29ezep0KSPzpA"=>{"token"=>"$2a$10$cS9gbe9UBICcgphZHRAENOMS6NlEe0Em1cNufY3LSRTPE.hRMabvi", "expiry"=>1481834221}}
...
```

It seems to me that the token I get back in URL is not correct.
Those anyone have an idea ?

Sorry It's a bit hard to explain.
Many thanks.

rails (4.2.4)
devise_token_auth (0.1.34)
devise (= 3.5.1)
angular2-token: 0.2.0-beta.1

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar challenges recently, and this was how I solved it.

Expose the 'access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client' for your backend. Check [here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#cors) and [here](https://github.com/neroniaky/angular2-token#commonproblems)

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
    allow do
       origins '*'
       resource '*',
          :headers => :any,
          :expose => ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'],
          :methods => => [:get, :post, :options, :delete, :put, :patch]
    end
end
```

Set your redirect_url of `path: /password, method: POST`. Check info [here](https://github.com/neroniaky/angular2-token#commonproblems)

We need to modify the reset_password_instructions.html.erb to point it to the api GET /auth/password/edit. More information provided [here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#usage-tldr).

E.g. if your API is under the api namespaces:

`<%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_api_user_password_url(reset_password_token: @token, config: message['client-config'].to_s, redirect_url: message['redirect-url'].to_s) %>`